# Examples of Lie algebras of the $BC$ root system type

Tags: lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

What are some examples of Lie algebras of the $BC$ root system type please? I am actually interested in the corresponding groups too. I heard that there were Lie algebras over $\mathbb{R}$ having $BC$ root system type. Can someone provide a definition, or at least, some references please?

Comment: @Travis: I think what the OP means is Lie algebras whose (rational = belonging to a maximal split torus) roots form a root system of the non-reduced type usually called $BC$. That can of course not happen for split Lie algebras / over algebraically closed fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, here is a quite generic example of simple Lie algebras over certain fields $k$ whose $k$-rational root system is of the non-reduced type $BC$. It works for any field $k$ of characteristic $0$ which has a proper quadratic extension, and gives a quasi-split form of type $A_{n \ge 2}$; I quote from example 3.2.10 (p. 53) of [my thesis](https://smf.emath.fr/publications/algebres-de-lie-semi-simples-et-leur-classification-sur-les-corps-p-adiques) (for a more geometric interpretation, cf. exercise 16.a to ch. VIII, §13 of Bourbaki's *Lie Groups and Lie Algebras*):

---

Let $k$ be any field of characteristic $0$ which has a proper quadratic extension $K = k(y)$  with $y^2\in k$, and let $\sigma \in Gal(K\vert k)$ satisfy $\sigma(y) = -y$; for $k =\Bbb R$, take $y=i$ (the imaginary unit $\in K=\Bbb C$), and $\sigma$ the complex conjugation.

Let $n \ge 2$, $d = n+1$, and consider, inside $\mathfrak{sl}_d(K)$ viewed as a $k$-Lie algebra, those matrices $(x_{i,j})$ which satisfy $x_{i,j} = -\sigma(x_{d+1-j, d+1-i})$; that is, those traceless $d \times d$ matrices over $K$ such that each entry is the negative conjugate of the one mirrored at the secondary diagonal (in particular, the entries on the secondary diagonal are $k$-multiples of $y$); or in yet other words, the traceless $d \times d$ matrices $(x_{i,j})$ over $K$ satisfying $(x_{i,j}) \cdot H + H \cdot \, ^t(\sigma(x_{i,j})) = 0$ where $H$ is the $d \times d$ matrix with entries $1$ on the secondary diagonal and $0$ else. A maximal split toral subalgebra is
\begin{align*}
\mathfrak{s} := \{ diag(x_{1,1}, ..., x_{d/2, d/2}, \;-x_{d/2, d/2}, ..., -x_{1,1}) : x_{i,i} \in k \}
\end{align*}
or
\begin{align*}
\mathfrak{s} := \{ diag(x_{1,1}, ..., x_{n/2, n/2},\; 0, \; -x_{n/2, n/2}, ..., -x_{1,1}) : x_{i,i} \in k \}
\end{align*}
according to whether $n$ is odd or even. One calculates that for odd $n$, the rational root system $\overline R$ is of type $C_{d/2}$, whereas for even $n$, it is of type $BC_{n/2}$.

---

Note that over $\Bbb R$, the above Lie algebra (for even $n$) is denoted by $\mathfrak{su}_{\frac{n}{2}, \frac{n}{2}+1}$ e.g. in Onishchik/Vinberg: [see Table 9 (p. 312) here](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/drutu/tcc2/onishchik-vinberg.pdf). The simplest case $\mathfrak{su}_{1,2}$ is fleshed out a bit [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2497093/96384) and in example 3.2.9, p. 51-53 of my thesis.

There are more simple Lie algebras over $\Bbb R$ whose real roots form a system of type $BC$. According to and with the notations of the above Onishchik/Vinberg reference, the full list is:

- $\mathfrak{su}_{p, l+1-p}$ ($l \ge 2$, $1\le p \le l/2$): rational root system $BC_p$ (complexification is of type $A_l$); for even $n=l$ the above was the special case $p=n/2$;
- $\mathfrak{sp}_{p, l-p}$ ($l \ge 3$ odd, $1 \le p \le (l-1)/2)$: rational root system of type $BC_p$ (complexification is of type $C_l$);
- $\mathfrak{u}^\ast_{2p+1}(\Bbb H)$: rational root system of type $BC_p$ (complexification is of type $D_{2p+1}$);
- $EIII$ (called $^2 E^{16'}_{6,2}$ by Tits in the Boulder Proceedings): rational root system of type $BC_2$ (complexification is of type $E_6$);
- $FII$ (called $F_{4,1}^{21}$ by Tits in the Boulder Proceedings): rational root system of type $BC_1$ (complexification is of type $F_4$).

Note: Over number fields, there might be some more, I am trying to work through Tits' list in the Boulder Proceedings.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you! I understood the example you explained. What are some standard references on the topic please? You mentioned Onishchik/Vinberg and your thesis. I am slowly making my way into algebraic groups, knowing only the corresponding theory over C only.

Comment: For semisimple algebraic groups / Lie algebras over $\Bbb R$, see the answers to this recent question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3121110/96384. For general fields, I found parts of Springer's textbook on *Linear Algebraic Groups* very helpful (in particular the second edition, the first dealt mainly with the alg. closed case). And there's always the big Borel-Tits article http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1965__27__55_0/, and the "Boulder Proceedings": https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~panchish/ETE%20LAMA%202018-AP/Borel_Algebraic%20Groups%20and%20Discontinuous%20Subgroups.pdf

Comment: Thank you! Particularly for the Boulder Proceedings, which I could not find online yesterday. I will have a look at the answer you referred to as well.